# Javascript check/uncheck all function. IE doesn't update

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
function checkUncheckAll(theElement) {
        var theForm = theElement.form, z = 0;
        while (theForm[z].type == 'checkbox' && theForm[z].name != 'checkall') {
                theForm[z].checked = theElement.checked;
                z++;
        }
}
```

theElement is the checkall checkbox at the bottom of a list of checkboxes. when clicked it calls this function to set all checkboxes in the same form to the value of checkall.

It works across all browsers aside from one glitch in IE. After clicking the checkall box it seems like the checkboxes are updated, but you don't see it. If you click anywhere on the page the checkboxes are then updated to their proper status. This happens for both checking and unchecking.

Comment: ... and welcome to StackOverflow @Kyle! You probably had no idea what you were getting yourself into when you asked this question. We all would love to know what you think. ; )

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Mike. While I appreciate everyone's enthusiasm nobody has actually addressed the issue. The issue is that the DOM elements don't get updated in IE after the function is called. Performing any action afterwards updates the DOM and the boxes get checked or unchecked as desired. The issue doesn't exist with FF or Chrome.

Comment: There must be some conflicting code on the page that IE doesn't like, but others don't have an issue with...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy without jQuery, which is unnecessary here.

```
function checkUncheckAll(theElement) {
    var formElements = theElement.form.elements;
    for (var i = 0, len = formElements.length, el; i < len; ++i) {
        el = formElements[i];
        if (el.type == "checkbox" && el != theElement) {
            el.checked = theElement.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

It turned out the main problem was that the `checkUncheckAll()` function was being called from a `change` event handler on a checkbox, which doesn't fire in IE until the checkbox loses focus, so the fix was simply a matter of changing it to use a `click` event handler instead.

Comment: While I feel pretty strongly that javascript without jQuery is scarcely javascript at all, I do like your good js form in declaring multiple local variables in the for statement.
The other reason for recommending jQuery is that the question was migrated from ServerFault, indicating that this is someone new to js. Finding jQuery can be a major help to new javascript users.

Comment: @TelegramSam: Thanks for the approval. I pretty strongly disagree with you about jQuery, including the part about recommending it to people new to JavaScript, but there you go.

Comment: Downvoter: I admit I'm in an impatient mood and have possibly challenged your belief in the sanctity of jQuery, but if you're going to downvote, at least explain. My answer is correct.

Comment: @TelegramSam - the first part of your first sentence is the best joke I've heard in a long time. Srsly. Made my day. :)

Comment: Oh wow, another unexplained downvote. Way to go, jQuery disciples.

Comment: @TelegramSam: No need, I don't care about the votes as such. I'm just... in a funny mood. But thanks. Getting grumpy on SO is a sure sign I need step away from the computer.

Comment: Thanks for the great banter Tim. Great way to end my day. : )

Comment: @Mike: Any time! I can do impatient grumpiness and childish petulance without even thinking, and the internet NEVER FORGETS.

Comment: +1 - No reason to over-complicate it...if you're *already* using jQuery, then by all means.  ...but including *any* library just to do what Tim's loop above does is borderline insanity.

Comment: This function adds needless complication. The way 'check' is determined in the original function is by the state of the checkall checkbox. There is no need to pass it as a variable.

Your script produces the same issue: The checkbxoes don't get updated in IE until another action is performed.

Comment: @Kyle: You're right, I misread the original function, and I'll change that. However, could you give more information on how you get the error? An example page, maybe?

Comment: Got it stripped down to its basic. Works fine in FF and Chrome. IE after you click select all, you have to click else where on the page for the check boxes to update.
http://cp1.cpasitesolutions.com/~step1pro/test.php

Comment: @Kyle: Ahhh, now I understand. Yes, the problem is that IE doesn't fire the `change` event until the checkbox loses focus. You need to use the `click` event instead.

Comment: Ahhh, I don't know how I missed that! Thanks so much Tim, I'll select this as the answer, unless you want to submit onclick as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll amend the answer to include the `onclick` bit.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It does require including a library, but it's well worth it! jQuery handles cross-browser js/DOM issues, and provides an excellent selector syntax and modification methods.

Additional examples similar to yours are hilighted in this Blog Post:

http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery

```
function checkUncheckAll(theElement){
    newvalue = $(theElement).is(':checked');  
    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']", theElement.form).attr('checked', newvalue);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? jQuery FTW! IMO, nobody should use javascript without it. +1

Comment: Amen! A JS library is the way to go if you are going to do DOM manipulation or interactions more than 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: @MikeGrace Or if you are going to do anything in Javascript without wanting to go rethink your career choice. :)

Comment: @galambalazs Works like a charm for me in IE7, FF, and Chrome.

Comment: @Alex: *"Why the downvote"* - because it doesn't actually changes anything?    
http://jsfiddle.net/ZsRm4/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/ZsRm4/1

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. Seriously, it is simply NOT THAT HARD.

Comment: @galambalazs calling `.attr()` with two arguments does set the attribute value.

Comment: @TelegramSam - Lol. I meant that the Demo works identical with or without jQuery (this is what doesn't change).

Comment: @galambalazs Ah. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Thank you for the link to jsfiddle.net galambalazs. Testing my original function on this page with IE and it works as intended without the issue I'm experiencing on my page. There must be conflicting code somewhere on the page hosting my function, I'll have to track it down.